# OnChanges on route.snapshot

Tags: angular

I have a component `ThreadsComponent` which can be changed by the elements of the  navigation bar composed of themes (`Light` or `Dark` in the example) and categories (`Darth Sidious` or `Darth Vader` in the example).

[image: example]

After I clicked on one of my category (`Yoda` in the example), I am not able to refresh my page with another category even if my route change :
For example `http://localhost:3000/threads?themeId=5b339149cf753310de75e2ed&categoryId=5b33915ccf753310de75e2ef`

How can I solve this problem?

Below the code I use :

Extract of my `topbar.component.html` :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin">Admin</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngFor="let theme of themes$ | async">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span [innerHTML]="theme.iconCode"></span>
          {{theme.name}}
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <li *ngFor="let category of theme.categories">
            <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/threads']" [queryParams]="{ themeId: theme._id, categoryId: category._id }">
              {{category.name}}
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Extract of my `thread.component.ts`:

```
export class ThreadsComponent implements OnInit {

  themeId: string;
  categoryId: string;
  category$: Observable<Category>;

  threads$: Observable<Thread[]>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private sectionStoreService: SectionStoreService,
              private threadStoreService: ThreadStoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.themeId = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('themeId');
    this.categoryId = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('categoryId');

    this.category$ = this.sectionStoreService.categories
      .pipe(
        map(categories => categories.find(item => item._id === this.categoryId))
      );
    this.sectionStoreService.getThemeCategory(this.themeId, this.categoryId);

    this.threads$ = this.threadStoreService.threads;
    this.threadStoreService.getCategoryThreads(this.categoryId);
  }
```

Extract of my `threads.component.html`:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="category$ | async as category; else loading">
  <div class="category-presentation">
    <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{category.description}}</p>
  </div>
```

Is it possible to do an `OnChanges` on route param? Because from my research I only found with data-bound elements.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The snapshot, as its name implies, provides a... snapshot of the params as they are when ngOnInit is called. Use route.queryParams instead, which is an Observable, emitting new query params every time they change, and thus allowing to reload data based on the new query params. The same goes for params and data, BTW.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, obviously it works better with `route.queryParams` :)